# IF a == b, then c = 1, else 0. How to turn this to a linear expression?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I want to turn the following condition into a linear expression:

If a == b, then c = 1, else 0.

How should I transform this into a linear expression?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use $c= \delta_{ab}$, with the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) .

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ continuous or binary?

Comment: a and b are integer values. a ranges from 1 to 24, b ranges from 1 to 17.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by linear expression you mean an expression of the form $c = ma+nb + p$ where $m,n,p \in \mathbb{R}$, which satisfies the given condition.

Linear expressions are not powerful enough to capture such an expression. This can be proved without much effort (for example, put $(a=b=0)$, $(a=1,b=0)$ etc to get values of $m,n,p$ and finally arrive at a contradiction).

Essentially, you want a function $f$ from  $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ which is the characteristic function of the set $\{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Perhaps if you give some context as to where this comes up and why you need a linear expression, I can be of more help.

Comment: Hi Gupta, I'm trying to write an optimization model using PuLP in python. The intuition of one of my constraints is like the logic I described. I heard big-M method can solve this type of problem, but I don't know how to exactly use the big-M method here. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can use a boolean expression like $c \equiv (a-b)(b-a) == 0$. This is true if and only if $a = b$ and hence $c$ would get the value True or $1$. I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: Then it would be a nonlinear function. As far as I know, PuLP does not support nonlinear optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce three binary variables $d_1,d_2,d_3$ which sum to 1, and model the three possibilities

$$
a-b \leq M(1-d_1),~ -M(1-d_1) \leq c \leq M(1-d_1)\\
-M(1-d_2) \leq a  - b \leq M(1-d_2),~ -M(1-d_2) \leq c-1 \leq M(1-d_2)\\
a-b \geq -M(1-d_3),~  -M(1-d_3) \leq c \leq M(1-d_3)\\
$$

If $a$ and $b$ are continuous, the model is not practically well-posed as you really cannot model equal vs not equal since solvers work with finite precision and tolerances around, say, $10^{-8}$. Hence, you would typically have to accept some region around equality where you think it is close enough, leading to

$$
a-b \leq -\epsilon + M(1-d_1),~ -M(1-d_1) \leq c \leq M(1-d_1)\\
-M(1-d_2)-\epsilon  \leq a  - b \leq \epsilon  + M(1-d_2),~ -M(1-d_2) \leq c-1 \leq M(1-d_2)\\
a-b \geq \epsilon -M(1-d_3),~  -M(1-d_3) \leq c \leq M(1-d_3)\\
$$