# Optimization of an objective where cost parameter takes step value

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have the following simplified optimization problem:

min $C*x$

s.t, some constraints

I want the following to be enforced as additional constraints:

$C=1$, when $0<x<=40$

$C=2$, when $40<x<=140$

$C=3$, when $140<x<=400$

How do i implement that as an MIP as I don't think this can be converted to a LP problem.

Comment: To clarify, if x takes a value of 120, the overall cost should be (2*120)=240; instead of, (1*40+80*2)=200.

Comment: You need to introduce three binary variables to represent the three regions and the behavior in each region, modelled using big-M strategies, exactly like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192080/if-a-b-then-c-1-else-0-how-to-turn-this-to-a-linear-expression

Comment: Are you sure you want the cost function to be discontinuous? Had you used a continuous version of this instead, it would be convex and LP representable

Comment: Yes, it needs to discontinuous, as the $C$ parameters represent different transmission line cost and $x$ represents the corresponding transmission line capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce three binary variables $d_i$ which sum to 1 and a variable $f$ to represent objective, and then use big-M to enforce that $d_1$ implies $0\leq x \leq 40, f = x $ etc.

To model $d_i$ implies $g(x)\leq 0$, you use $g(x) \leq M(1-d_i)$.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the solution correctly. Do you mean the following? $min f$, subject to, $C*x<M(1-d_1)$,$C*x>M*d_1$. And likewise, I continue for other constraints. How does that constraint $f$ in the objective function. Also, I need to pass the value of $x$ into a lower level problem; so i should be able to extract that value. Appreciate your response.

Comment: No, you minimize $f$, and then to model the first segment you have $x-40 \leq  M(1-d_1), x\geq  -M(1-d_1), -M(1-d_1) \leq f  - 1x\leq M(1-d_1)$, and then similarly for the two remaining regions

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out.